# Zurb foundation select input - 2 arrows issue

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am just wondering why the Zurb Foundation's select input works fine on their website:
[foundation forms](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/forms.html)
And when I copy the excact code from their example and put on my website - there occurs a 'second arrow issue' on firefox:
[image]
The question is what would be the best fix for that issue.
I use:

```
select {
    background-image: none;
}
```

I am not sure if it is the best way to work around that, of course remembering to apply that code only for firefox.
Any ideas how to fix the problem without any 'hacks'?

Comment: are u running firefox? and which version?

Comment: The latest version of firefox - 32.0.1, and the latest version of foundation - 5.4.0. When I test it on chrome the problem vanishes. It is quite common issue as I heard.

Comment: I have the Firefox 32.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 but I didn't find this bug when I implement the form (zurb one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's seems to be a [Firefox bug](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/5363) for version 30.0 and up on certain device. Unfortunately I have no work around... other than removing the arrow on the select box.

Comment: It is true, I have come to similar conclusions, but why does select work fine on foundation's website then? :(

Comment: Yes it does appear even on their websites too. (On my other desktop) when I zoom in I see half of the arrow. and the more I zoom in the more I see the arrow. this is on a [120% zoom](http://i121.photobucket.com/albums/o205/guinslym/stackoverflow/foundation_zps094a46be.png)

Comment: Aww, of course! Your answers clarified my concerns. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3):

For me worked:

```
select {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

It is a fix for other browsers too.

Answer (score 0):

Im using Firefox 26.0 and the select arrow doesn't show at all, just the standard dropdown arrow box.

Here is my solution to the issue:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
select {
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;
    base64, PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZlcnNpb249IjEuMSIgeD0iMTJweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMjRweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIzcHgiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA2IDMiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDYgMyIgeG1sOnNwYWNlPSJwcmVzZXJ2ZSI+PHBvbHlnb24gcG9pbnRzPSI1Ljk5MiwwIDIuOTkyLDMgLTAuMDA4LDAgIi8+PC9zdmc+);
    background-position: 100% center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: '';
}
```

}

Working example: [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/defonic/La9kud85/)